# How to add an extra properties argument to a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, textbox

I have a winForms with `textboxes`.  Each `textbox` will show setting values from an .ini file. Some of the .ini file values are encrypted and will require the values to be decrypted before placing the value inside the `textbox`. I already created a function:

```
storeIniValueToVar(string iniSection, string iniKey, bool? encrypt)
```

Is it possible to extend the `textbox` properties with a custom argument such as boolean? encrypt?  My thinking was to pass the custom argument boolean? encrypt value to the `storeIniValueToVar` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a generic property called Tag. You can store any kind of strings in it. 
The disadvantage is that the return type is Object, but you don't have to derive from your UI control.

Example:

```
    private void OnTextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var updatedTextBox = sender as TextBox;
        object tagObject = updatedTextBox.Tag;

        // Further converting of the tag here...

    }
```

Set the events of your textboxes (here TextChanged) to one single EventHandler and you can get the TextBox instance and the tag as well.

Comment: This seems like an interesting way to approach what I would like to accomplish.  After reading through your example, I am still unsure how to set/pass(encrypt=true or just true) using a .Tag.

Comment: Never-mind, I understand after searching google about the .Tag property :-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking to add an additional property to the `TextBox` class which will indicate whether the text contained within it it should encrypted/decrypted when it is stored/loaded from the ini file.

What you could do is subclass `TextBox` and add your own properties:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public bool Encrypt { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you use `MyTextBox` instead of `TextBox` on your forms.

Comment: Should I add that additional class to the Form.cs or Program.cs?

Comment: Nest would be to create a separate file like MyTextBox.cs